# How to pass the object of data to the bootstrap model using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created the bootstrap model and i am opening the the model on button click, Now the problem is i want to pass the object of data to that model so once the user enter the comment in the model i will get the comment as well as my object back for identification, can some one help me out with the solution

```
MY HTML CODE 
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mymodal">
            <div class="modal-dialog displayMainmodel" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #aeb3b7; color:White">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Insert Your comment</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <textarea [value]="precomment" #comment placeholder="Enter your Comment" 
                            rows="4" cols="50"
                                style="resize: none; border: 1px solid #aeb3b7;width: 100%;">

                        </textarea>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="justify-content: center; border:none">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                            style="background-color: #3CB371;" 
                       (click)="submitcomment(comment.value)">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                        dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




   My Ts code 
             openpopup(datacommentid,name){
               console.log("data is",datacommentid,name)

                 this.data.forEach(element => {
                 console.log("sjdksa",element)

                  if(element.id==datacommentid){
                   this.precomment=name.comments
                }
  
             });
             $('#mymodal').modal();

            }

            submitcomment(mycomment){
              console.log("the comment is",mycomment)
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shown.bs.modal` event

Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/ozud4cgq/9/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var element = $('<div>Modal is opened</div>');
  $('.modal-body').append(element);
})
```

Comment: Title of the question "to the modal" and question text "from the modal" don't match - they probably want `hide.bs.modal` - but the usage is essentially the same as this answer.  See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events